# On Demand Resource App Thinning

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, on-demand-resources

I have been using image localization, I want to use the on-demand resource concept.
I want to implement this such that if the user selects the english language, the app will display the image related to English and at this time I want only the english image to be  downloaded not the other language images using on-demand resources.
This is what I tried:

```
    NSSet *tags = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"english", @"france", @"italy", nil];
    NSLog(@"tags:%@", tags);

    NSBundleResourceRequest *request = [[NSBundleResourceRequest alloc] initWithTags:tags];

    [request conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL resourcesAvailable) {
        if (resourcesAvailable) {

            [self.img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"imageName", nil)]];
        }
        else {

            [request beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    if(error == nil) {


                        [self.img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"imageName", nil)]];

                    }
                    else {

                        NSLog(@"the error is: %@", error);
                    }

                }];


            }];
        }

    }];
    [request endAccessingResources];
```

When I use this all the resources are downloaded when using English as my language. If someone can help me that would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the user's current language:

```
NSString* language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then select the tag you want to download: (default now is English)

```
NSString *tagString = @"english";

if( [language isEqualToString:@"fr"] ){
    tagString = @"france";
} else if( [language isEqualToString:@"it"] ){
    tagString = @"italy";
}

NSSet *tags = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:tagString, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting the tags `english`, `france`, and `italy`, so you're getting all the resources tagged `english`, all the resources tagged `france`, and all the resources tagged `italy`.

If you want to request the resources for only one tag, include only that tag in your `NSBundleResourceRequest`.

Comment: thank you for your input, if dont mind can you tell me how to solve this issue, i mean i have 3 tags want to download one at time how to get it

Comment: If you want to download only one tag, request only one tag. Look at your code — see where you're specifying a set of three tags? Change it to a set of only one tag.